# Hibernate and EJB: how to correctly use @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss, transactions

I have the following code that I am expecting to persist **all or none** of the `entities` in the method.

However, it is behaving that some `entities` are created and others are not - i.e. the whole `transaction` is not being rolled back.

Why is this so?

Note - I am running my code as an `EAR` file in `JBOSS EAP` server

```
  @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void createCompanyStatuses(String client, CompanyStatusPostDTO companyStatusPostDTO) {
    
            EntityManager entityManager = null;
    
            try {
    
                CompanyStatus companyStatus = new CompanyStatus();
                companyStatus.setCompanyLabel(candidateMaskedStatusPostDTO.getCompanyLabel());
    
                entityManager = entityManagement.createEntityManager(client);
                entityManager.persist(companyStatus);
    
                for(Integer employeeStatusId: companyStatusPostDTO.getEmployeeStatuses()){
    
                    CompanyStatusEmployeeStatus companyStatusEmployeeStatus = new CompanyStatusEmployeeStatus();
                    companyStatusEmployeeStatus.setEmployeeId(employeeStatusId);
                    companyStatusEmployeeStatus.setCompanyId(companyStatus.getCompanyId()); //todo - how will get this?
                    entityManager.persist(CompanyStatusEmployeeStatus);
                }
    
            } catch(Exception e){
                log.error("An exception has occurred in inserting data into the table" + e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                entityManagement.closeEntityManager(client, entityManager);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer valid for `Hibernate`.

`TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` is not supported.

It is hard to implement rollback on java object. Imagine scenario when:

1. Transaction started
2. Object created and saved
3. Subtransaction started
4. Object modified
5. Subtransaction rolled back.

You expect object to be in state it was before subtransaction started, so you need to trace information about modification of that object inside subtransaction and ability to roll those modification back.

Alternatively you could reload state from DB, but you need to track which object belong to which transaction.

I assume developers just decided that it is too much effort for little gain.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is it not possible to implement any form of rollback for my current code? thanks

Comment: AFAIK subtransaction isn't supported in any shape of form. So you need to change your algorithm. You may try to start whole new transaction in different thread, but keep in mind that rolling back current transaction won't affect database changes made in new one (and you can get some concurrency issues )

Comment: I mean rewrite you code in a way that doesn't required subtransactions.